# R group by with each grouped element associated with most common factor

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, data-cleaning, r-factor

I want to group by column `a` and choose the most common factor `b` for each unique `a`. For example:

```r
tibble(a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), b = factor(c('cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'))) %>%
    reframe(b = most_common(b), .by = a)
```

I want this to produce:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat |
| 2 | dog |

However, the `most_common` function doesn't exist. Is there an efficient R function for this purpose? This must be a pretty common need for data cleaning (what I need it for). I searched and found people implementing `mode` functions. I could use one of those, but they seemed inefficient. Is there a better approach to this overall problem?

Comment: Actually R has a `mode` function (with other purpose though). Here's some suggestions for finding the mode (most common value) with R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/how-to-find-the-statistical-mode

Comment: "They seemed inefficient" - what about the `fmode` function from the *collapse* package as noted here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60765505/496803 - at the `r-faq` question for this topic? I would be shocked if that was not somewhat efficient as the processing is all pushed to compiled code, and it has a specific method for a grouped tibble.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `table` + `max.col`

```
d <- table(df)
data.frame(
  a = as.numeric(row.names(d)),
  b = colnames(d)[max.col(d)]
)
```

which gives

```
  a   b
1 1 cat
2 2 dog
```

or using `dplyr` like below

```
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(b = names(which.max(table(b))))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      a b
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 cat
2     2 dog
```

Comment: I like your second solution, but `summarise` is deprecated. Apparently, `reframe` is supposed to be used instead.

Comment: @at. - nope, `summarise` is not deprecated. Its use to return 0 or >1 rows is deprecated in preference to `reframe`. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html